# Swift2 protocol extension NSObjectProtocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

What I want is auto implement delegate method for some NSObjectProtocol conforms to some protocol, but I try hard, not get it done.

Demo is down below

Update for more accurate

=========================================================================

I got one protocol `PagedLoadable` to get info of what collectionView needs, then `extension NSObjectProtocol  where Self: Delegatable`, auto config for the object implement `PagedLoadable`

```
protocol PagedLoadable {
    var count: Int { get }

}

protocol Delegatable: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


}

extension PagedLoadable where Self: Delegatable {
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return  count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
        return cell
    }
}

class vc: UIViewController {

}

extension vc: PagedLoadable {
    var count: Int {
        return 1
    }
}

extension vc: Delegatable {

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Type 'vc' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

Comment: Why not define a direct extension to `Delegatable`?

Comment: @findall Could you show me? T_T

Comment: @InvokerLaw Sorry that I've tested what I said, but the compiler crashed with segfault, even though it was passed. (I tried `extension Delegatable { /* Implementations required by UICollectionViewDataSource */ }`)

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol
//Class SurveyDownloadHandler

```
protocol SurveyDownloadHandlerDelegate {

     func surveyDownloadSuccessfully(notiExpireRemainingTime : Int)
     func surveyDownloadConnectionFail()
}


class SurveyDownloadHandler: NSObject  {

    var delegate: SurveyDownloadHandlerDelegate! =  nil
}
```

//for calling method back to Class A                                `delegate.surveyDownloadSuccessfully(notiExpireRemainingTime)`

// Class A

```
class A : UIViewController,SurveyDownloadHandlerDelegate{

   let surveyDownloadHandlerObject : SurveyDownloadHandler = SurveyDownloadHandler()

   @IBAction func onTapClick(sender: AnyObject) {

          self.surveyDownloadHandlerObject.delegate = self
          self.surveyDownloadHandlerObject.startDownloadingSurvey()
     }
  }

   func surveyDownloadSuccessfully(notiExpireRemainingTime : Int)
   {
   }
   func surveyDownloadConnectionFail()
   {

  }
}
```

Comment: What I want is make a "plugin module" for some protocol with runtime, and no need to implement

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement extension to protocol with exception of inheritance. After some experiment I could remove your error with following approach.

```
    //: [Next](@next)
    protocol PagedLoadable {
        var count: Int { get }
    }

    protocol Delegatable: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    }
    extension Delegatable {

    }
//Removed since code will not be able to resolve dependency 
    extension PagedLoadable /*where Self: Delegatable*/ {

        func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return  count
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
            return cell
        }
    }
```

//One way is

```
    class vc: UIViewController,PagedLoadable, Delegatable {
        var count: Int {
            return 1
        }

    }
```

//or you can do this way too

```
extension vc: PagedLoadable, Delegatable {
    var count: Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @Girish Kolari , I've been updated the description,pls take a took at it

Comment: I did need /*where Self: Delegatable*/ bcoz I need to set delegate to Delegatable object

Comment: You can do where Self: Delectable if it is pure swift object with no reference to Objective C run time.

Comment: Just got curious - in your code object of vc is its delegate object - what is the error you have to set it as delegate object